# Are there any online virtual tabletops with 2.5D or 3D views?

Tags: tools, battle-map, tool-recommendation

Currently my group uses Roll20.net for online gaming but I want something more visually appealing and variable.

I found [a list of VTTs](http://rpgvirtualtabletop.wikidot.com/choosing-a-vt) but the only alternatives to top-down is a 3D virtual tabletop application that is still in alpha/beta.

Are there any completed online 2.5D (aka "isometric" or "3/4 view") or 3D tabletop systems? Chat is not important as we can just use Skype.

An example of 2.5D would be like this:

[image: description]

Comment: @BrianS That would probably be a decent full answer, eh?

Comment: This is a good question. But if I was being honest, I upvoted it for the Diablo screenshot.

Comment: Do you require the macros, etc? If not, [Tabletop Simulator](http://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/) may be an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For what it's worth, there are isometric tilesets available for Roll20. A search for "isometric" on the Roll20 Marketplace turns up several results, including [Isometric 3D Desert Tomb](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/set/402/isometric-3d-desert-tomb), [Isometric Sewer](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/set/396/isometric-sewer), and [Isometric Dungeon](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/set/388/isometric-dungeon) (by Plexsoup; I am not affiliated).

The description pages for Plexsoup's isometric sets also includes instructions for creating a fairly seamless isometric experience within Roll20:

> #### Tips for optimal experience:
>
> - Turn off the Roll20 grid
> - Make a new page
> - Set the Page Size to 96x96
> - Set the Scale to “"1 unit = 7 feet”"
> - Set the background to a nice, dark color
> - Go to the Map layer
> - Start at the top left corner and lay tiles from back to front
> - Right click on tiles and set “"To Front”“ or ”“To Back”“ as required
>
> #### Notes about isometric or side-view play:
>
> - The ruler will only show proper distances along cardinal direction. ie: diagonals will show the wrong distance. Counting squares still works fine.
> - Dynamic lighting requires special care around doors, because you want players to see the door.
> - Character Facing is less obvious than in top-down play. Rotating side-view character tokens will make them “"lie down”“. Great for showing casualties! To change facing, right click a character and ”“flip horizontal”"

These instructions can assist you in creating your own isometric maps, potentially even for free if you can find appropriate art online or you have the necessary art skills yourself.

For a different "3D" experience in Roll20, the marketplace also has [Dungeon Depth Tiles](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/set/384/dungeon-depth-tiles) and [Dungeon Depth Tiles Supplement I](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/set/393/dungeon-depth-supplement-i) (by Stephen Shomo; I am not affiliated). Rather than being an isometric view as Plexsoup has achieved, Stephen has created a top-down view of a 3D environment, so that nothing needs to change for the behavior of your tokens, dynamic lighting, measurements, etc.

If you have access to a Mentor subscription, Stephen has also been working on a [dungeon generation script](https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/1213067/thinking-about-new-style-of-random-dungeon-generator-with-forced-perspective-and-mini-map-dot#post-1213067) using his Dungeon Depth Tiles set. The way his tiles are designed also [makes dynamic lightning simpler](https://app.roll20.net/forum/post/1337177/restrict-token-movement-plus-box-style-dynamic-lighting-equals-quick-and-easy-setup-and-modification#post-1337177):
[image: box lighting]

Comment: If some of the best video games ever used the style in that last pic, it should be good enough for anyone!

Answer (score 2):

[Tabletop Simulator](http://store.steampowered.com/app/286160/) is full 3d and allows you pick up and move anything, but it'll make your game look very much like an actual tabletop-game and I'm not sure that's the style you're aiming for. It's also not really designed specifically for RPG games, but I figured I'd at least give you the option to check for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

How about the aptly named [3D Virtual Tabletop](http://www.3dvirtualtabletop.com/index.html)? It's currently available on iPad, iPhone and Android.  You can import your own maps and minis from images on your device.  A web browser version for Mac and PC is in the works.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of, although I did see a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xdXtDWcy3A) of a guy using the [unreal engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4) that looked interesting. Something like [panda 3d](https://www.panda3d.org/) also has potential for a [3d game board](https://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Sample_Programs:_Chessboard).

I also saw an isometric map from torstan

[image]

used with [maptool](http://www.rptools.net/?page=maptool), but it was technically 2d, just with an isometric view.

Edit: After some thought; I wasn't really following your 2.5d until after a few reads; isometric presenting 3d aspects in a 'flat' 2d format. I don't see why any 2d tool would limit this, but I imagine things like automatic move calculations could be thrown off, especially if there's perspective to the image. (Some isos are equidistant like torstans.) I would imagine auto-reveal/dynamic-lighting might also be thrown off a bit. However, I should note, I've used non-game image tools to do maps and used image layering to reveal as necessary. A 'game' tool isn't strictly necessary. Google hangouts and GIMP might give you more options.

Answer (score 1):

I am working on something like this, it works with roll20, essentially a large map and isometric assets. https://www.patreon.com/alexdrummond

[image]